# content type not correctly set by php script

Tags: php, jquery, http-headers

I have the following php code that runs after validation:

```
try {

    if (isset($filtered) && !isset($errors)){
        $p['email']=$filtered['email'];

        # check if email exists
        if ($user->userExists($p)){
            $msg['error'] = false;
            $msg['msg'] = 'This email address is already in our database';
        } else {
            # insert user data into database
            $user->saveUser($filtered);
            $msg['error'] = false;
            $msg['msg'] = 'Successful! Go back to our homepage.';
        }
    } else {
        # echo errors back
        foreach ($errors as $value) {
            $msg['error'] = true;
            $msg['msg'] = $value;
        }
    }
```

I prepare the json data as follows:

```
        # header encode
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        # return json encoded data
        echo $encoded = json_encode($msg);
```

A direct array like this one below works fine.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$msg['error'] = true;
$msg['msg'] = 'Please enter an email address.';
echo $encoded = json_encode($msg);
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem with my php logic could be. Kindly help.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Any error messages?  What's the content type set to?  What happens if you view the url?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do `echo json_encode($msg)` to be 'proper'. Or do the assignment on one line and then echo out the variable on another.

Comment: Not sure what the actual problem you're having is (I can't spot any obvious things), but there's a probably unrelated logic error in your sample. However many `$errors` there are, you'll only return one back to the front end, as you're overwriting `$msg['msg']` in the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: @Mark B Why does that matter? I do stuff like that all the time, never cause me any problems and (until now at least) I didn't consider it particularly bad practice-y...

Comment: Unless you're using $encoded again, why assign it at all?  just `echo json_encode($msg);`

Comment: @Mark B I do that to avoid creation of too many variables which will consume some memory space. Check this: [link](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html)

Comment: Thanks @Toast I will rectify that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference I can see there is that in the version that works, you call `header()` *before* anything else.

Try moving

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

above the try/catch. I have a suspicion that the reason you are getting this problem is because you are implicitly accessing the array `$msg` before you have created it, which throws an `E_NOTICE` (or it might be `E_STRICT`, I can't remember) and causes something to be written to the output buffer, so the headers are sent, and you can no longer manipulate them - although if this were the case I would expect it to break your JSON as well...

Regardless, try the above and report back.

Comment: I have tried to move the `header()` portion above the try/catch but still no luck. I agree with you that there seems to be some bit of code that implicitly send headers. I have include files in the same script. Could this be the cause?

Comment: What you are looking for is something that causes output - so it could be any `echo`, `print`, `print_r`, etc call that writes data to the output buffer (there are many other functions that do this as well, like `system`)- and it could be something that causes an error, where the error message is printed. You can use the [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function to find out if/where the headers have been sent.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I had a conditional somewhere in my code that was never evaluating to allow for the json to be returned. Thanks for your insight.